# onclick and href together not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am creating an html page where i have three tabs on click on tab i want make that active and also i want to goto some other page
here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">
      <a class="tab-link" href="#events?eventType=Movies&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="return theFunction();" i18n="EVENT.MOVIES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> MOVIES</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">

      <a class="tab-link" href="#events?eventType=Performance&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" i18n="EVENT.PERFORMANCES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> PERFORMANCES</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">

      <a class="tab-link" href="#events?eventType=WorkShops&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" i18n="EVENT.WORKSHOPS"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> WORKSHO PS</a>

    </div>
```

here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function theFunction() {
         alert("dfsdf");
       if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
                 $(".active").removeClass("active");
                 $(this).addClass("active");
        }else{
            return false;//this prevents flicker
       }
     }
</script>
```

can someone help me in this

Comment: Update your code in fiddle so it will be easier to review the cod

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab-link').click(function(){
            alert("dfsdf");
           if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
                     $(".active").removeClass("active");
                     $(this).addClass("active");
            }else{
                return false;//this prevents flicker
           }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="theFunction();"
```

You don't need a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="tab-link" href="#events?eventType=Movies&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="theFunction(); return true" i18n="EVENT.MOVIES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> MOVIES</a>
```

It will work for you

or

```
   <a class="tab-link" href="#events?eventType=Movies&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="return theFunction();" i18n="EVENT.MOVIES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> MOVIES</a>

function theFunction(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    alert("dfsdf");
   if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
             $(".active").removeClass("active");
             $(this).addClass("active");
    }else{
        return false;//this prevents flicker
   }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: it is not giving me any alert and also not making it active

Comment: @Kabali - add event.preventDefault in your code otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: where i have to add that

Comment: Can you please check this codepen link http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/VKkZNP of my previous code

Comment: still its not working first thing that alert itself is not coming

Comment: The link that i shared in comment have you checked that?

Comment: Last but the least heck this link and update according to you requirement http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/rrBxXE

Comment: same code i wrote but the facebook is opening but the alert is not coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122165/discussion-between-kabali-and-raja).

Answer (score 0):

Add This
**target="_blank"** to anchor tag

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFuntion()" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

Comment: What you are trying to answer he want both execution and your are not writing anything in href. dnt you think wrong approach

Comment: Study the question again